# Load a resource into a frame work from an app

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I have a framework I wrote for an app and now I am writing some unit tests for it. To complete the test suite, I need to load a configuration file from the main app into my framework's unit tests. When I try to use `Bundle(for: self.classForCoder)` and load that config file, it returns nil all the time. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither your framework, nor the tests for it, can access your main app bundle that way.

Since your app provides the config file to the framework, your tests can do the same. If you can use a test config file, just add it to your test bundle. If you need a copy of the actual config file, then make a copy.

(You may want a Run Script build phase to do the copying. Don't forget that just making a copy isn't enough — you still need to add it to the test target.)

Comment: Dang! That means I will have to main both the config and the test config files. Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: That’s why I suggest adding a script phase to copy the main config to test config.

Comment: Then I shall write the script.